# Weird Issue with the info/second View on iPod

Tags: iphone

I just started testing my App on my iPod, and I have to click numerous times the info light button which is attached to my second view to show. I have to click it probably 10-15 times, then it finally triggers the second view to show. Of course in Simulator it works fine, but on the iPod it's rather weird that I have to keep hitting it to finally work. Then, sometimes it works without trying to hit it a ton of times. It's rather buggy. Curious if my code is crappy or what other issues are making this feature act weird.

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil];

    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is not related to your issue, but you do have a memory leak in your code, you should be calling [second release] after calling presentModalViewController

Answer (score 1):

It's a small button, sluggish precision on the touch mesh at the corners and fat fingers.

Make a bigger rectangle around the info button to make it easier to hit - or completely swap out the button for a larger button.

Comment: how do i make the area around the info light larger (http://screencast.com/t/M2Y3ZWNlYz)?

Comment: Yup, I'd also go for the "custom" style button.